# Conditionally echo opening and closing HTML tags

Tags: php, html

A lot of times in PHP, it is necessary to conditionally echo opening and closing tags. For example, when getting a list of elements, you only want to include the `<ul> ... </ul>` if there are more than 0 elements (`<li>`s) to display. The most obvious solution is like this:

```
<?php
    $count = getCount();
    if($count > 0) {
        echo "<ul>";
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
         // echo our items
         echo "<li>" . getItem() ."</li>";
    }
    if($count > 0) {
        echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

But we have the same `if( ... )` twice. Is there a better way to conditionally echo the `<ul>` tags ?

Comment: This can of course have other applications other than lists, e.g. echoing a `<div> ... </div>` only if there is content to echo.

Comment: Why do you think you NEED two if's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go... one `if`:

```
<?php
    $count = getCount();
    if($count > 0) {
        echo "<ul>";
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            // echo our items
            echo "<li>" . getItem() ."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

This also skips an unnecessary for loop, which you currently have in your code :)

Of course I jest a bit.  Once you finally get past the point of wanting to write spaghetti code, then you can look into various templating engines.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to output HTML is to use a template engine and do not output any HTML directly via PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two `if` statements.  You can just do it all in one statement.

```
if($count > 0) {
    echo "<ul>";
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
     // echo our items
     echo "<li>" . getItem() ."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```